# Printing to a network printer through ASP.net using IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, printing

I have an android application that sends information to my ASP.net "server" hosted locally through IIS. That server then attempts to print a label based on information given from the android app to a printer named `"\\My-PC\DYMO LabelWriter 450"`. I then create an instance of 
`System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` and set the `PrinterName` attribute to the aforementioned printer name. When I look into the PrinterSettings when I am debugging, I see that it has the following errors:
1. `'printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsPlotter' threw an exception of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException'` 
2. `'printDocument.PrinterSettings.SupportsColor' threw an exception of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException'`

I can continue to run the code, but it throws an error that says 
`Settings to access printer '\\My-PC\DYMO LabelWriter 450' are not valid."` 

with a  `System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException`  error.

I am using:

- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- IIS (Version 10.0.15063.0)

My code to print is as follows:

```
Friend WithEvents printDocument As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
...
Public Sub print()
    Try
         printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\My-PC\DYMO LabelWriter 450"
         printDocument.Print()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The code to set up what to print on the document is elsewhere and not pertinent.

I have been stuck on this problem going on two weeks now and have exhausted my abilities in programming and searching online for answers. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

"My-PC" = Machine 1

"GSC" = Machine 2

It may be useful to know that the code is being hosted through Machine 2. I am using Remote Desktop to gain access to Machine 2 through my machine (Machine 1). The printer I am trying to access through Machine 2 is connected to Machine 1. While I have been able to print successfully to Machine 1's printer while the two machines are connected through Remote Desktop, this goes away when the Remote Desktop connection is severed.

Ex: I am able to remote desktop into machine GSC and print to the printer hooked up to My-PC. However, when I am on GSC physically, I cannot print to the printer on My-PC in my code. I have connected/installed it locally on GSC but it isn't working properly.

Comment: What user / security context is your IIS app pool running as?  Does it have access to the printer?

Comment: @squillman I have tried running through an account on the server machine that has access to the printer and through the DefaultAppPool identification which also has access to the printer. The printer is available for: Everyone, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES, Account Unknown, CREATOR OWNER, DefaultAppPool, User, and Administrators.

Comment: @MutedDisk That's my bad, it is actually referenced as "DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy 1) on My-PC" on the remote machine. I have tried using a multitude of different names to attempt to get the printing process to work properly and none of them have worked so far. So when reading the code, you may substitute "\\My-PC\DYMO LabelWriter 450" with "DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy 1) on My-PC". Both names yield the same results.

Comment: @MutedDisk I have cleaned up the question and provided an example of the problem for clarification.

Comment: @MutedDisk it was set up that way already. I have printed multiple test pages from GSC. The problem isn't connecting to it through a wizard or prompt box, but the problem is connecting to the printed through ASP.net and IIS when I am running my code.

Comment: @JacobPinney the only thing left then is permission. if you are able to print a test page from the locally installed printer on GSC then you definitely have a permission issue.

Comment: add APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and IIS_IUSR to your printer's permission

Comment: I have tried and failed to add GSC\IUSR or GSC's APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and IIS_IUSR. This is because when I go to add a user to the printer, it says the location to select users from is "My-PC", and I need that to be changed to "GSC". How do you add GSC\IUSR to My-PC\DYMO LabelWriter 450?